Project does not find SDK (Visual Studio 2022)
Few months or year ago I installed VS, used it purely for testing, wrote small C++ projects and saved all that in source/repos folder. But then I uninstalled VS and reinstalled it now, but when I create console project in .NET (namely cross-platform projects, .NET 5+) I get error that I can't find sdk in source/repos path, in system environment variables there are paths "C:\program files\dotnet" and "C:\program files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App", but even with all that, when I create project I get this error, in my "sdk" folder there is only folder with version 9, and in sdk manifests folder there are folders with versions 8 and 9, but in C:\program files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\ there are versions 6/8/9. I can't understand at all what this is connected with, debugging and assembly are not available to me at all
In the command line, when entering "dotnet --list-sdks" version 9 appears, and when entering "dotnet --list-runtimes" version 6/8/9 appears
Maybe I need to specify a different path for the project?
Solutions or just explanations
The problem was solved, it turned out that you just needed to add DOTNET_ROOT to the system variables..
